# Pack data into binary string in Python

Tags: php, python, pack

Using the PHP [pack()](http://www.php.net/pack) function, I have converted a string into a binary hex representation:

```
pack('H*', $SECURE_SECRET)
```

How can I get the same result in Python?
I tried `struct.pack`, but the result is not the same.

Comment: What's the problem with struct.pack?

Answer (score 7):

`pack('H*', $value)` converts hexadecimal numbers to binary:

```
php> = pack('H*', '41424344')
'ABCD'
```

In Python, you can use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) to get the same result:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify
>>> unhexlify('41424344')
>>> 'ABCD'
```